# Showing that a radical function is continuous

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

I want to show that $f(x) = x^{1/5}$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb R$.
My try:
Fix $\epsilon > 0, c \in \mathbb R $ and try to find $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) -f(c) | < \epsilon$ .
The case for $c = 0$ is quite straightforward. When I use the identity to expand $a^5 - b^5 $, I get: $$|x^{1/5} - c^{1/5}| = \frac {|x-c|}{|x^{4/5} + c^{4/5} + (xc)^{2/5} + x^{1/5}c^{3/5} + x^{3/5} c^{1/5} |} \leq \frac{|x-c|}{|x^{1/5}c^{3/5} + x^{3/5} c^{1/5}|}$$ because $$ x^{4/5} + c^{4/5} + (xc)^{2/5} \geq 0$$ for all reals.
But I am stuck from here..
Any help would be great

Comment: You can use $$a^5-b^5 = (a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)$$

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot I could use the binomial expansion. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I present an answer in three different levels of analysis (quite literally): a first, dirtier, more cautious approach; a second, slicker, more daring approach; and finally, a generalized version of the second approach that hopefully offers some insight into why it worked in the first place. You can choose which one you like best!

---

**1. Dirty proof.** Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $c > 0$. Then, if $x<c$, we have
$$|x^{1/5} - c^{1/5}| = c^{1/5} \left|1-\left(\frac xc\right)^{1/5}  \right| \leqslant c^{1/5} \left| 1 - \frac xc \right| = c^{-4/5}|x-c|; $$
taking $\delta_1 := c^{4/5}\varepsilon$ we obtain $|x^{1/5}-c^{1/5}| ​\leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-c|\leqslant \delta_1$.

If instead $c<x$, then by the same argument
$$|x^{1/5} - c^{1/5}| \leqslant x^{-4/5}|x-c| \leqslant\begin{cases}
x^{-1}|x-c| & x \in (0,1). \\
x|x-c| & x > 1,
\end{cases} $$
Suppose $x >1$ and define $\delta_>'$ in such a way that, *a posteriori*, it works as before: it's not too hard to guess $\delta_2 := -\frac c 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt{c^2+4\varepsilon}$. Then, seeing as $|x-c|\leqslant \delta_2$ would imply $x \leqslant c+\delta2$, and thus
$$\begin{split}
|x^{1/5} - c^{1/5}| &\leqslant (c+ \delta_2)\delta_2 = \left(\frac c 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt{c^2+4\varepsilon} \right)\left(-\frac c 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt{c^2+4\varepsilon} \right) \\
&= \frac 1 4 (c^2+4\varepsilon) - \frac 1 4 c^2 = \varepsilon.
\end{split} $$
Similarly, if $x \in (0,1)$, we can define $\delta_3:=\frac c 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt{c^2- 4\varepsilon}$, provided $\varepsilon < c^2/4$ (which can always be arranged). In that situation we also see that $|x-c|\leqslant\delta_3$ implies $c-\delta_3\leqslant x$, and thus again $|x^{1/5}-c^{1/5}| \leqslant (c-\delta_3)\delta_3= \varepsilon$ (try it).

Continuity on $(0,+\infty)$ follows by choosing $\delta := \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3\}$ and from the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ and $c$.

If $c=0$ the relevant inequality follows immediately with $\delta:=\varepsilon^5$, so the function is continuous at $0$; finally, continuity on $(-\infty,0)$ follows from the oddity relation $(-c)^{1/5} = -(c^{1/5})$.

(Notice that our choice of $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ *and* $c$: [this doesn't have to be so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity). See below!)

---

**2. Prophetic proof.** Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $c\neq 0$. Suppose an angelic being manifests itself to you and gifts you with the knowledge of a $\delta$ which does not depend on $c$: $\delta := \varepsilon^5$. Indeed, this works. As before, suppose $c<x$ (i.e. $0<c/x<1$), so that $$\frac cx \leqslant  \left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^{1/5}, \implies 1- \left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^{1/5}\leqslant1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right),$$ and similarly
$$\left[1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)\right]^{1/5}\geqslant 1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right).  $$
Hence
$$
\begin{split}
|x^{1/5} - c^{1/5}| &= \frac{|x^{1/5}-c^{1/5}|}{|x-c|^{1/5}} |x-c|^{1/5} = \frac{c^{1/5}\left|1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^{1/5}\right|}{c^{1/5}\left|1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right) \right|^{1/5}} |x-c|^{1/5} \\
&\leqslant \left|\frac{1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)}{1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)} \right| |x-c|^{1/5} = |x-c|^{1/5};
\end{split}
$$
we can exchange the role of $x$ and $c$ to obtain the same inequality for the case $x<c$ (although we need to require $x\neq 0$, which is not a problem). So, as long as $|x-c|\leqslant \delta=\varepsilon^5$, we have the desired $|x^{1/5}-c^{1/5}|\leqslant\varepsilon$.

The angel's $\delta$ also works for $c=0$, as we've already shown, so continuity (uniform continuity!) on the whole of $\mathbb R$ follows from the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$.

(But how did the angel know that this $\delta$ would work? See below!)

---

**3. Transcended proof.** Let $0<\beta<1$, and $f : x \mapsto x^\beta$ with $x \in (0,+\infty)$.
We can repeat the same argument as in the second proof, replacing $1/5$ with $\beta$, to conclude that
$$\begin{split}
\sup_{x\neq c}\frac{|f(x)-f(c)|}{|x-c|^\beta}&=\sup_{x\neq c} \frac{|x^{\beta} - c^{\beta}|}{|x-c|^{\beta}} \leqslant  1 < + \infty.
\end{split}$$
This is equivalent to saying that there is a finite constant $a>0$ (in this case the optimal choice is $a=1$) such that
$$|f(x)-f(c)|\leq a|x-c|^\beta; $$
any function of this kind is said to be [$\beta$-Hölder continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) (with constant $a>0$) on $(0,+\infty)$ – written $f \in C^{0,\beta}(0,+\infty)$. (This is a generalization of [Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), which stems from a similar condition but with exponent $\beta=1$.)

On the domain $(-\infty,0)$, the function $f$ is defined only when $\beta$ is a rational number that has an odd denominator when expressed in minimal terms (let this be the case from now on). The $\beta$-Hölder continuity extends to this domain because of the parity relation $f(-x)= \pm f(x)$ (sign depending on the parity of the numerator of $\beta$). Also, clearly we see that, with the optimal choice of Hölder constant $a=1$,
$$|f(x)-f(0)| = |x^{\beta}| \leq |x-0|^{\beta}, $$
so we actually have that $f\in C^{0,\beta}(\mathbb R)$.

Does $\beta$-Hölder continuity with constant $a>0$ on $\mathbb R$ imply regular old continuity? Yes, because it implies uniform continuity: given an $x \in \mathbb R$ and a $\varepsilon>0$, we can take $\delta := (\varepsilon/a)^{1/\beta}$ (the angel's $\delta$!), so that for all $y$ with $|x-c|< \delta$ we have
$$|f(x)-f(c)|\leq a|x-c|^\beta < a\delta^\beta = \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\delta<\dfrac c2$ so that $x>\dfrac c2$.

Then the long denominator is at least

$$(2^{-4/5}+2^{-3/5}+2^{-2/5}+2^{-1/5}+1)\,c^{4/5}$$

and

$$|x^{1/5}-c^{1/5}|<\frac{|x-c|}{c^{4/5}}<\frac{\delta}{c^{4/5}}.$$

So you can take

$$\delta=\min(\frac c2,c^{4/5}\epsilon).$$

Answer (score 1):

After the last step you mentioned the denominator i.e.

$$|x^{1/5}c^{3/5}+x^{3/5}c^{1/5}|=|x^{1/5}||c^{1/5}||c^{2/5}+x^{2/5}|\ge |x^{1/5}||c^{3/5}|$$

as both terms in the last modulus are positive

Now for $c\ne 0\ \exists \delta\ |x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow\ x\in [c/2,3c/2]$ in whatever order the set is applicable.

Using this assumption the net expression can be written as $\le\frac{|x-c|}{|(c/2)^{1/5}\times c^{3/5}|}$ following which we can easily continue to show that the function is continuous using epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not quite sure why you want $x \in [c/2, 3c/2]$

Comment: I used that range to set a lower bound for x which in turn helps me set an upper bound for the whole expression.